# Liquid template - Differentiate between null and empty nodes

Tags: maps, azure-logic-apps, liquid-template

I am using liquid template in my LogicApp for data transformation. I need to differentiate if a json node is empty, null.

So in json if i have `"Name":""`  `"Name":null` , then I need to differentiate between them. I observed that all the below 3 conditions(== "" , == empty == blank) return true for both of these cases. So how I explicitly check if it is null or just ""

```
{% if content.Name == "" %}

{% endif %}

{% if content.Name == empty %}

{% endif %}

{% if content.Name == blank %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does this work: `{% if content.Name == null %}`?

Comment: {% if content.Name == null %}  will not help i have tried this already

Comment: @techresearch, did you manage to find a way? I'm having the same problem and i even tried to compare against nil... i honestly don't understand all the hype using liquid for JSON... i even have to deal with the quotes :S

Comment: @FEST I didn't get any solution to this, Let me know if you have got any fix.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Fortunately for me, I found that the end system treats nulls ad empties the same way so that made things simpler for me